# Oracle Forms: Obtain multiple values from a data block on the same form

Tags: forms, oracle

I have multiple data blocks on the same form.  All these values display ok when the parent form is displayed - I can see multiple values displayed correctly. But when I wish to perform an action based off of these values dependent on the the parent form, the procedure that runs when a key is pressed, requires the multiple values from the child data block to be available by using the identifier for each row.

Like this:

```
    if :CHILD_BLOCK.ID is not null and :CHILD_BLOCK.ID = p$_id then
        write_name(:CHILD_BLOCK.NAME);
    end if;
```

If the child_block has only one value - this works. If the child_block has more than one value, the :CHILD_BLOCK.ID is always null.

How to retrieve multiple values from a child data block and use them in a procedure?

Answer (score 0):

In Forms, to access the values in each record in a multi-record block, you have to navigate through the block record-by-record.

For example:

```
GO_BLOCK('CHILD_BLOCK');
FIRST_RECORD;
LOOP
    EXIT WHEN :SYSTEM.LAST_RECORD = 'TRUE';
    write_name(:CHILD_BLOCK.NAME);
    NEXT_RECORD;
END LOOP;
```